Inconsistency in evaluating complex integral using two different approaches
I am trying to evaluate the following integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}$$. I know that the following formula for integrals $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=\pi\iota R(X-axis)+2\pi\iota R(\text{Upper half plane})$$ provided poles on x-axis are of first order. Therefore, to perform the integral in question, I write it as $$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos z}{1+z^2}$$. Now I know that there are no poles on the x-axis and the only pole is in the upper half plane. $$R(z=i)=\frac{\cos \iota}{2\iota}=\frac{e+1/e}{4\iota}$$. So, I expect the answer to be $$I=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(e+\frac{1}{e}\right)$$. However, there's another way to do this. One can write the integral as $$I=\frac{1}{2}\oint\frac{e^{\iota z}}{1+z^2}$$. The residue at $z=\iota$ is $$R(z=i)=\frac{e^{-1}}{2\iota}$$. Thus the contour integral is just $\frac{\pi}{2e}$ and since the integral from the semicircle drawn in the upper half plane is $0$, the only contribution is from the x-axis. Hence the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2e}$, which is correct. However, I don't understand the mistake in my approach.

By the way $\cos(i)=\dfrac{e+1/e}{2}$ so $\dfrac{\cos(i)}{2i}=\dfrac{e+1/e}{4i}$

@Conreu Right, thanks! Fixed it.

Any reference to the formula for the integral via poles along x-axis and in upper halfplane?

@EgorLarionov It can be found in Mathematical Methods for Engineers and Scientists Volume 1 by KT Tang on Page 163. Here's the relevant part from the book.

I see the issue now. The formula is valid only if the integral on a semi-circular contour in the upper half plane is 0, which can happen if $\frac{z\cos z}{1+z^2}\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow\infty$.

If you write down the definition of $\cos z$ in terms of $\exp(\pm iz)$ and think about what this means for purely imaginary $z$, you'll find some bad news for  the circular part of the contour.

As you said, the problem here is that the arc integral for the first integral does not vanish for $z\to\infty$. Let's parametrize the integral (supposing the arc lies on the upper half plane) and apply the triangle inequality to obtain an upper bound:
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\int_\Gamma\dfrac{\cos(z)}{1+z^2}\,\mathrm dz\right|\leq \int_\Gamma\left|\dfrac{\cos(z)}{1+z^2}\right|\cdot\left|\mathrm dz\right|&=\int_\Gamma\left|\dfrac{\cos(z)}{1+z^2}\right|\cdot\left|\mathrm dz\right|\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_\Gamma\left|\dfrac{e^{ix}e^{-y}+e^{-ix}e^{y}}{1+z^2}\right|\cdot\left|\mathrm dz\right|\\
&\!\!\!\!\overset{z=Re^{i\theta}}{=}\lim_{R\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi\left|\dfrac{e^{iR\cos\theta}e^{-R\sin\theta}+e^{-iR\cos\theta}e^{R\sin\theta}}{1+R^2e^{i2\theta}}\right|R\,\mathrm d\theta\\
&\sim \lim_{R\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi\dfrac{e^{R\sin\theta}}{R}\,\mathrm d\theta\to\infty, \enspace \sin\theta>0
\end{aligned}$$
In contrast, if we do the same for the second integral we'll see that you can actually apply that formula since
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\int_\Gamma\dfrac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2}\,\mathrm dz\right|&\leq \int_\Gamma\left|\dfrac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2}\right|\cdot\left|\mathrm dz\right|\\
&=\int_\Gamma\dfrac{e^{-y}}{|1+z^2|}\cdot\left|\mathrm dz\right|\\
&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^\pi\dfrac{e^{-R\sin\theta}}{|1+R^2e^{i2\theta}|}R\,\mathrm d\theta\\
&\sim \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^\pi\dfrac{e^{-R\sin\theta}}{R}\,\mathrm d\theta\to 0,\enspace \sin\theta>0
\end{aligned}$$

Still though, the function you proposed, $\dfrac{z\cos z}{1+z^2}$, $\not\to 0$ when $z\to\infty$ by the same argument.
